# auto-increment value in update conflicts with internally generated values

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement, innodb

I've been getting this error from an insert on duplicate update query in MYSQL randomly every now and then.
Any idea what's going on? I can't seem to reproduce the error consistently it occurs sometimes and then sometimes not.

Here is the query in question:

```
INSERT INTO friendships (u_id_1,u_id_2,status) VALUES (?,?,'active') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

And the schema describing the table is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `friendships`;
CREATE TABLE `friendships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_id_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','pending','rejected','blocked') DEFAULT 'pending' NOT NULL,
  `initiatiator` enum('1','2','system') DEFAULT 'system' NOT NULL,
  `terminator` enum('1','2','system') DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirm_timestamp` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`u_id_1`,`u_id_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Do you really think updating a **primary key** is a smart move? Look at your update part closely, you'll find out why it happens. Rule: **never** touch the primary key. Never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement isn't helping you at all here.

You are taking the LAST_INSERT_ID, which is the auto inc of the last successfully inserted row, and trying to update the duplicated row with that id. This will always cause a duplicate primary (you're trying to change the id of some row to match the id of the last thing you added)

Comment: Ah I see. I think I've solved the issue with
`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id`

Though the reason I was updating to last_insert_id  was so that I could insert that value into another table

Answer (score 1):

A separate consideration is to check the source for duplicates.  I had a simple audit table

```
INSERT INTO table
 field1, field2, ... , field3
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE row_id=row_id;
```

where `field1` is an `INDEX` but not `UNIQUE` with `row_ID` as `INTEGER UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

Ran for years, but an unexpected duplicate row triggered this error.

**Fixed by de-duping the source.**

Possibly a trivial point to many readers here, but it cost me some head-scratching (followed by a facepalm).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to either

- Insert a new row, *or*
- Update an existing row with 'active'

Then

```
INSERT INTO friendships (u_id_1,u_id_2,status)
        VALUES          ( ?    , ?    ,'active')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
            status = 'active';  -- I changed this
```